# SQLITE3 Select запросы

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite3

Всем Привет.

Имеется данный кусок кода который собирает информацию о приложении и отправляет ее клиенту по websocket.

Проблема заключается в этом куске кода:

```
        // Всего пользователей
        var count_user_ = 0;
        db.each("SELECT COUNT(id) as cnt FROM `vk_app_all_visits` WHERE `id_app`=?", [ row.id_app ], function(err, rows) {
            count_user_ = rows.cnt;
        });
```

После выполнения данного куска кода в результате получим count_user_ который равен 0.
Если добавить console.log в db.each, то получим нужный результат.
Такое чувство что переменная объявлена не через var, а через let которая будет видна именно в том блоке, где объявлена.

```
db.serialize(function() {
    var response = [];
    db.each("SELECT id, title, id_app, (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `vk_app_sender_app` WHERE `uid`=?) as count FROM `vk_app_sender_app` WHERE `uid`=?;", [uid, uid], function(err, row) {
        var count = row.count;

        if(count > 0) {
            var title = row.title;

            // Урезаем название приложения
            title = title.substring(0, ((title.length >= 30) ? title.length-3 : title.length ))
            if(title.length >= 30) title = title + "...";

            // Всего пользователей
            var count_user_ = 0;
            db.each("SELECT COUNT(id) as cnt FROM `vk_app_all_visits` WHERE `id_app`=?", [ row.id_app ], function(err, rows) {
                count_user_ = rows.cnt;
            });

            response.push({id: row.id, title: title, idapp: row.id_app, count_user: count_user_});
        }
    }, function complete(err, found) {
        if(found == 0) {
            returning = {action: "vk_sender", type:"getappuser", status: 0};
        }

        if(found > 0) {
            returning = {action: "vk_sender", type:"getappuser", status: 1, info: response};
        }

        ws.send (JSON.stringify(returning));
    });
});
```

Как правильно получить количество записей в таблице `vk_app_all_visits` в данном случае?

Comment: `count_user_` можно использовать только внутри блока db.each потому как вызов асинхронный, он происходит не в тот момент, когда написан, а позже. и та строка которая идет после него в коде выполняется _до_ того как данные были получены из БД. перенесите response.push внутрь db.each. остальную логику то же надо бы внимательно просмотреть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему изменив sql запрос на:

```
SELECT vk_app_sender_app.id, vk_app_sender_share_app.uid_share, vk_app_sender_share_app.uid, vk_app_sender_share_app.id_app, vk_app_sender_app.title, (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `vk_app_sender_share_app` WHERE vk_app_sender_share_app.uid_share=?) as count FROM vk_app_sender_share_app, vk_app_sender_app WHERE vk_app_sender_share_app.id_app = vk_app_sender_app.id_app AND vk_app_sender_share_app.uid_share=?;
```

Результат:

```
db.serialize(function() {
    var response = [];

    db.each("SELECT vk_app_sender_app.id, vk_app_sender_share_app.uid_share, vk_app_sender_share_app.uid, vk_app_sender_share_app.id_app, vk_app_sender_app.title, (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `vk_app_sender_share_app` WHERE vk_app_sender_share_app.uid_share=?) as count FROM vk_app_sender_share_app, vk_app_sender_app WHERE vk_app_sender_share_app.id_app = vk_app_sender_app.id_app AND vk_app_sender_share_app.uid_share=?;", [uid, uid], function(err, row) {
        var count = row.count;

        if(count > 0) {
            // Урезаем название приложения
            var title = row.title;
            title = title.substring(0, ((title.length >= 30) ? title.length-3 : title.length ))
            if(title.length >= 30) title = title + "...";

            response.push({id: row.id, title: title, idapp: row.id_app});
        }
    }, function complete(err, found) {
        if(found == 0) {
            returning = {action: "vk_sender", type:"getappshareuser", status: 0};
        }

        if(found > 0) {
            returning = {action: "vk_sender", type:"getappshareuser", status: 1, info: response};
        }
        ws.send (JSON.stringify(returning));
    });
});
```